# Данные из формы не отправляются в БД при использовании Spring Security

Tags: mysql, spring-security

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на "Добавить статью" происходит следующее:

```
@PostMapping("/blog/add")
public String blogPostAdd(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String anons, @RequestParam String full_text, Model model) {
    Post post = new Post(title, anons, full_text);
    postRepository.save(post);
    return "redirect:/blog";
}
```

То есть данные отправляются в БД, а затем я могу просмотреть все эти сатьи на другой странице моего web-приложения. Однако при использовании Spring Security (я реализовал авторизацию) при нажатии на кнопку обрабатывается спринговский error и открывается моя страница error.html. И в базу данных ничего не записывается. Не знаете почему использования авторизации портит процесс передачи данных из формы в БД?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/error", "/blog", "/about").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/blog/add", "/blog/{id}/edit").authenticated()
                    //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Покажите класс WebSecurity, где вы настраивали безопасность.

Comment: @am233dmg отредактировал вопрос. Когда я перехожу на страницу blog/add (та, где форма со скриншота), то у меня запрашивается авторизация (так как эта страница добавлена в `antMatchers().authenticated()`. И когда я нажимаю кнопку "Добавить статью", происходит ошибка и ничего не добавляется в БД, а если убрать Spring Security, то все заработает. Может еще pom.xml скинуть? Хотя не знаю, может ли быть в нем какая-то ошибка..

Comment: То есть получается вы переходите на blog/add, вас перекидывает на логин, вы водите логин и пароль, залогинились, потом опять заходите на blog/add, нажимаете добавить статью, и вас кидает на error.html? я правильно понял?

Comment: @am233dmg да, я захожу на blog/add, меня перебрасывает на авторизацию, я ввожу данные, нажимаю кнопку "войти" и меня опять перебрасывает на blog/add

Comment: а можно ссылку на гитхаб?

Comment: @am233dmg https://github.com/private-doggo/blog/tree/Auth - вот это с авторизацией, а в ветке development - без

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117084/discussion-between-hot-penguin-and-am233dmg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте http.csrf().disable() в методе configure(HttpSecurity http) в классе WebSecurityConfig, тем самым отключив защиту csrf, но если вы хотите это использовать, то вам надо настроить его.

Comment: я не знаю как я бы сам до этого додумался, ты лучший, от души!!!